# Labeling points on a graph with their coordinates in parentheses

Tags: plotting, graphics, formatting, labeling

I need to create some graphs in *Mathematica* with a bunch of labels, such as axes labels, graph labels, etc. In particular, there must be some points that must be labeled with their coordinates. Thanks to Internet search and this website in particular, I learned how to use the `Epilog` option. So I can do things like

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}, Epilog -> {Text[y == x^2, {0.5, 0.5}]}]
```

to label an equation or

```
 ListPlot[{{1, 1}}, Epilog -> {Text["(1,1)", {0.5, 0.5}]}]
```

to label a point. Thru my experimenting, as you can see in these two examples, I figured that meaningful *Mathematica* inputs can be used in `Text`, but meaningless (for *Mathematica*) would cause an error message, so I do them as strings in quotes.

Now here's a problem. I need to label a point whose x-coordinate is 2/3, and I want it to look as a stacked fraction. I can't type coordinates of points in parentheses without quotes because for *Mathematica* it's an error. But if I type it in quotes, the parentheses don't stretch vertically, which doesn't look right.

[image: my ListPlot samples]

Can anybody advise a solution to this problems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't mind using boxes and `DisplayForm` then this will work for you:

```
ListPlot[{{1, 1}}, 
 Epilog -> {Text[
    DisplayForm@
     RowBox[{"(", FractionBox["2", "3"], ",", "1", ")"}], {0.5, 
     0.5}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: No, I don't mind using anything, if it gets the job done! This output looks perfectly as what I want.

Answer (score 6):

Here are two possibilities. The first one has the advantage of allowing control of color, font properties, etc. The second one gives better element spacing.

```
ListPlot[{{2/3, 1}}, Epilog -> {Text[Style[{{2/3, ",", 1}}, "InlineFormula"], {0.5, 0.5}]}]
```

[image: plot1]

```
ListPlot[{{2/3, 1}}, 
  Epilog -> {Text[MatrixForm[{{2/3, ",", 1}}, TableSpacing -> {0., 0.3}], {0.5, 0.5}]}]
```

[image: plot2]

Comment: good solution but too much white inner spacing in there between the numbers. If these good be squashed closer they will look better.

Comment: @Nasser. painfully aware of that. Working on it, but so far no good results.

Comment: @m_goldberg: `MatrixForm[#, TableSpacing -> {0, 0}]`

Comment: @rasher. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @m_goldberg: thank you very much for these suggestions! As a follow-up question, if I might: what exactly is `InlineFormula`? I couldn't find it in _Mathematica_ documentation.

Answer (score 3):

If you can live with "{}" instead of "()", then a simple solution is to use `TraditionalForm`

```
ListPlot[{{2/3, 1}}, Epilog -> {Text[Style[TraditionalForm[{2/3, 1}],Red], {0.5, 0.5}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

if you want "()" instead of "{}" then will try something else.

If you do not want paranthesis at all:

```
ListPlot[{{2/3, 1}}, Epilog -> {Text[Style[Row[{TraditionalForm[2/3], ",", 1}], Red],
 {0.5, 0.5}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

btw, there seems to be a bug in Mathematica, as it is not able to parse the following in TeXForm. The idea is to use TeXForm to typeset the labels. But Mathematica does not like the following:

```
ToExpression["\\left( \\frac{2}{3} , 1 \\right)", TeXForm, HoldForm]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But the above is valid Latex code:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The idea is to use Latex for typesetting things instead. (this way one can have a balanced () instead of using {} ). If TeXForm would have worked, then you could then do the following

```
ListPlot[{{2/3, 1}}, 
 Epilog -> {Text[Style[ToExpression["\\left( \\frac{2}{3}, 1 \\right)", 
  TeXForm, HoldForm], Large], {0.5, 0.5}]}]
```

But this now does not work.  But one coordinate works:

```
ListPlot[{{2/3, 1}}, Epilog -> {Text[Style[
ToExpression["\\left( \\frac{2}{3} \\right)", TeXForm, HoldForm], Large], {0.5, 0.5}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Also, it is really strange, since "\left(" and "\right)" do not even show up in the final output.

Comment: I had tried `TraditionalForm` myself. But the problem is exactly that I have to have it in parentheses. I didn't know the trick with using TeX input, so thanks for this one! Too bad (and weird) it doesn't work in this case...